# Flask app in debug mode won't show info or debug log messages

Tags: python, flask, logging

I'm starting a flask application like this:

```
from idapi.wsgi import app
app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

Where `app` is an object of a subclass of `flask.Flask`. Within the application, I'm only ever calling `app.logger.<level>` (or `self.logger.<level>` within the class itself). I'm never importing the Python `logging` module itself.

My understanding was that when startring a flask app with `debug=True`, I should see see messages from `app.logger.debug(...)` and `app.logger.info(...)`, but I'm not.

I can solve this problem by explicitly configuring the root logger:

```
import logging
from idapi.wsgi import app

logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')

app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

Or I can use `app.logger.warning(...)` instead. What could be going on here...am I incorrect in my understanding of how logging is configured by Flask when running in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but in the [documentation of Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) I've seen that you need to set variable FLASK_ENV to development if you want to see debug messages:

> To enable all development features (including debug mode) you can
> export the FLASK_ENV environment variable and set it to development
> before running the server:
>
> $ export FLASK_ENV=development
>
> $ flask run